# Automatically sending GIFs in discord

Tags: python, datetime, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I added a bot to Discord and added various functions in Python.

I want to automatically send GIFs at a specific time and on a specific channel.

After configuring and starting the bot, nothing happens. No error is displayed, and the console is silent.

Below is a part of the code for this function.

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all()) 

async def send_gif(channel):
    print(f"Sending gif to channel {channel}")
    gif_id = "Here's the gif id"
    gif_url = f"Here's url"
    await channel.send(gif_url)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel_id = "Here's the text channel ID"
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if now.hour == sample hour and now.minute == sample minutes:
            await send_gif(channel)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

I would like the bot to send specific gifs at a specified time and on a specified channel.

I checked several times I was entering the correct gif IDs, channel IDs, and URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you didn't miss any symbols on `on_ready` event.

Maybe the error is in

```py
...
    if now.hour == sample_hour and now.minute == sample_minutes:
...
```

Also, check that you defined `sample_hour` and `sample_minutes` variables before referring them in the code.

If still doesn't work try using the `ext.tasks.loop` decorator, if you don't know how to, take a look to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=ext%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop)

If it's not the thing causing the error, comment in this message and I will **try** to edit this message as fast as possible for solving doubts.

Comment: When I typed here "sample hour" or "sample minutes" I meant this is example in my code I have smth like that 
'if now.hour == 22 and now.minute == 55:'
but thats on me I should have done it right away.